# How to send array of objects in props to a custom component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an array when I fetch from the API by using axios get request as follows:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    console.log("here");
    let accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("accessToken");
    const response = await axios
      .get(API_URL + "/feed", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setFeedItems([]);
        setFeedItems((feedItems) => [...feedItems, ...response.data]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

I have a custom component which is Report.js and I want to send some information from this screen to that component by using the following code:

```
{isLoading == false && (
        <FlatList
          style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }}
          data={feedItems}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Report
              name="mustafa"
              username="mustafa123"
              responsibleInstitution="responsible"
              userId={item.userId}
              category={item.category}
              location={item.location}
              institutionId={item.institutionId}
              description={item.description}
              upvotes={item.upvotes}
              comments={item.comments}
            />
          )}
        ></FlatList>
```

The shape of the data that is coming from the API is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6228a72cfc2ce87bb0b5f908",
        "userId": "61cab704ee5f9a5cc3bd844c",
        "institutionId": "61cabb2da10a9147a53e6480",
        "solutionId": null,
        "description": "Kayıp ilanı..",
        "category": "Missing",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": "6228c0933ab2f166af0a9d23",
                "userId": "61cab704ee5f9a5cc3bd844c",
                "text": "Tamam kardeş anladık",
                "date": "2022-03-09T14:58:27.091+00:00"
            },
            {
                "id": "6228c98534572422056eb565",
                "userId": "61cab704ee5f9a5cc3bd844c",
                "text": "Tamam kardeş anladık 3",
                "date": "2022-03-09T15:36:37.256+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "upvotes": [
            "61cab704ee5f9a5cc3bd844c"
        ],
        "location": null,
        "report_image_link": null,
        "file": null,
        "date": "2022-03-09T13:10:04.273+00:00"
    },
```

As you can see from the data, the 'comments' field has an array of objects with id, userId, text, and date fields. Whenever I run the code, I get the following error which is caused by the `comments={item.comments}` line.

The error:  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, userId, text, date}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

What I want to do is that, whenever user click a button in the Report.js component, I want to open up a modal and present the comments to the user on that component. Do you think I should change my way? How can I send the comments information to the Report component? If my approach is incorrect, what should I do?

Comment: How does `Report.js` look like?

Comment: I was just showing the comments in <Text>props.comments</Text> which is absolutely incorrect, I will try to show them by using a list or something else, do you think I am able to get the comments information without a problem?

Comment: *"Objects are not valid as a React child"* - What specific line throws that error?  Where specifically are you trying to render a JavaScript object?  The error itself is pretty specific... Somewhere the code is including directly in the rendered output a JavaScript object, which React has no idea how to render.  The code shown doesn't appear to be doing that.  So what is?

Comment: You can not display comments inside Text Tag like you mentioned. Use a flatlist instead and inside the render of flatlist you can wrap each comment in the Text Tag. This will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Since `comments` is an array of objects, you cannot pass it as a `child` to a `Text` component. Now, it depends on how you want to visualize your data. Here is a possible solution using `FlatList`. You could replace the rendered component with whatever suits you the best.

```js
const dummyData =  [
            {
                "id": "6228c0933ab2f166af0a9d23",
                "userId": "61cab704ee5f9a5cc3bd844c",
                "text": "Tamam kardeş anladık",
                "date": "2022-03-09T14:58:27.091+00:00"
            },
            {
                "id": "6228c98534572422056eb565",
                "userId": "61cab704ee5f9a5cc3bd844c",
                "text": "Tamam kardeş anladık 3",
                "date": "2022-03-09T15:36:37.256+00:00"
            }
        ]

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummyData);
  

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return <Text style={{margin: 20}}>`ID: ${item.id} userId: ${item.userId} text: ${item.text} date: ${item.date}`</Text>
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```